# Error on putting focus on InputTextMask through Icon on React Native

Tags: react-native

After I read several answers, but I couldn't come up with a solution.

I need to touch on the icon to put the focus on the InputTextMask, but an error occurs:

> refInput.current.focus is not a function

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {TextInputMask} from 'react-native-masked-text';

export default ({Icon, placeholder, value, onChangeText, mask}) => {
    let refInput = useRef(null);

    const getFocusInput = () => {
        refInput.current.focus();
    };

    return (
        <View>
            <Icon width="32" height="32" fill="white" onPress={() => getFocusInput()} />
            <TextInputMask
                ref={refInput}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                value={value}
                onChangeText={onChangeText}
                type={mask}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

I'm using React Native 0.64 and React 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that `react-native-masked-text` ref return you a MaskedText class, not the TextInput itself, to get the TextInput you will need to use on method as they show in their documentation, just change:

```
refInput.current.focus();
```

to

```
refInput.current.getElement().focus()
```

hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot ;)